# Impedir Scroll ao Abrir Teclado no Navegador do Celular ReactJs

Tags: html, css, css3, react, mobile

Preciso da ajuda de vocês! Não sei se já perceberam, com certeza já, mas quando estamos em uma página web no celular e por algum motivo o teclado abre, é como se ele empurrasse a view pra cima e cria um scroll pra navegar nela.
Tem alguma forma de ao invés de empurrar a view pra cima, ele "achatar" ela, ou alguma forma só de desabilitar essa rolagem que ele cria? Já tentei colocar overflow: hidden em vários lugares como no body ou na div principal e não funciona.